# Including non-standard packages in PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to create python executable using PyInstaller package:

The PyInstaller compiles my super simplified example code below without any error but gives error during runtime. This is because I am using "xlrd" package which is considered a `non-standard` package. The "xlrd" package was downloaded from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/0.9.3.

After searching for a while on web, I realized that I need use some `hooks` but couldn't figure out how.

Which file do I need to include (and where) and what will be its content?

`hello.py`

---

```
print("inside the file: Working here...")
import xlrd
print("Hi")
```

Error

---

```
HP-ZBook-15:~/Desktop/hello/dist/hello$ ./hello
inside the file: Working here...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named xlrd
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: this might help (haven't done it personally) [PyInstaller: Package Python Applications (Windows, Mac and Linux) | Python Central](http://www.pythoncentral.io/pyinstaller-package-python-applications-windows-mac-linux/)